# jquery datatables stateSaveCallback doesn't work like it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I use stateSaveCallback it not always works so good, Refreshing the page will let me stay on the paginate page of the table but when I leave the page to another page on the website and come back it sometimes goes instead of going back to the right page to another page. For example I'm on page 3 and I leave the page with the table and come back to the page with the table sometimes it goes to page 2 or 1 but most of the time page 3 like it should.

Does anyone have any idea what maybe interfering with my code that it sometimes doesn't work?

My code:

```
$('#table1').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true,
      "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
            $.ajax( {
              "url": "--my url--",
              "data": data,
              "dataType": "json",
              "type": "POST",
              "success": function(){}
            } );
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`stateSaveCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) allows the saved state to be stored off the client, which is exactly what you're doing. Your problem is that you haven't then defined the [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) to retrieve that state information when the page is revisited.